# Adding static content to Wordpress posts page?

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I know I have a static page for my home page in Wordpress.  I also have a page called "Rate Entries" as my blog page.  After showing this to my client, and then showing her the admin section of Wordpress, she began typing a paragraph into ***Pages >> All Pages >> "Rate Entries" >> Edit***.

The big problem here, as you all know, is that if "Rate Entries" is my posts page, that *page* content does not show there, only the *posts*.  Is there any way to add that page content to the top of the posts page?  I had hoped to find a plugin to do this, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you wanting to show your rate entries page as the home page? Please provide more explanation, and maybe even the website url

Comment: No, actually I am not.  I already have a home page called "Welcome" that has a few paragraphs of static content.  If you would like to see what I have, please see:

[link](http://www.paintyourwagonaward.org/)

Comment: Note, the welcome page is static, and the "Rate Entries" page has (well, right now only one entry) via post.  I need to have a paragraph on the "Rate Entries" page, and I'd love to have it from what was typed into the Pages >> All Pages >> "Rate Entries" >> Edit area.

Comment: So your rate entries page pulls all posts with rate entries? Seems to act similar to an archive.  Why not make your rate entries a page of its own and have the owner update the page vs posts.  Or maybe I'm still not following

Comment: Well, since the only posts that will be there are posts with rate entries, yes.  The idea is that my client takes entries she receives via email, and puts them in as posts, allowing the general public to rate each entry.  She wants text that she defines to be static on top of any page that shows posts.  In this case, there's only one posts page.

Comment: The closest plugin that I found to what I'm looking for is "list-posts" by MAGSHARE.  It allows me to put in **[[LIST_POSTS]]** to a page that I can then turn static.  The only trouble is that the display of the page doesn't look like the way I have already set up the posts to look like.  SO CLOSE!

Comment: add `the_content()` into the page template before the loop resets the post data

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  crowjonah, it appears you're closest to the answer in that it is code that had to be placed in the index page before the loop.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you've set a custom page for the posts in the Wordpress backend *(Settings > Reading)*, you just need to add a few lines of code to your **index.php** file in your theme. Like so:

```
//grab the id of the page set in the backend 
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');

//grab the post object related to that id
$posts_page = get_post($posts_page_id);

//display the content if any
if( $posts_page->post_content ){
    echo wpautop( $posts_page->post_content ); //uses wpautop to automatically add paragraphs
}
```

In your case, you can add the code to display the loop below this code.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a hardcoded paragraph at the top of entries page before the list of all entries, Why not create a template page, assign it to your rate entries page and hardcode your paragraph in the code so it's always on the top.

Read about page templates [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)

**Update**

Have you tried doing a [sticky post?](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts)  that should solve your problem

Comment: I could add static content, but that's not what the client wants.  The client wants the content she has typed in after she selected **Pages >> All Pages >> "Rate Entries" >> Edit** as she may want to change her mind without getting me involved.

Comment: Update answer, see above

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found that I had to insert into the *index.php* page in order to get what I need accomplished.  Right before the loop that cycles through the posts as ***crowjonah*** had mentioned.

```
    <?php $page = get_page_by_title( 'Rate Entries' ); ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="etnry-title"><?=$page->post_title;?></h1>
        <p><?=$page->post_content;?></p>
    </header>
```

What this does is take the page title and content for the page, and place it right above where the posts spill out.  This way, she can edit that text, and it will update on the posts page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a text widget. By using a plugin called "Display widgets" I can make sure that this text only displays on the blog page.