# How To Add WORDPRESS SHOW CONTENT OF STATIC POSTS PAGE ABOVE POSTS LIST

Tags: wordpress, blogs

is there any way to add content to my WordPress static blog page.

i tried to install plugin it not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some Other Sources

Method 1: Paste the below code in function.php

```
// Add content of page called “blog” to the page that contains the list of blog posts
add_action ( ‘__before_loop’, ‘add_blog_page_content_before_post_list’);
function add_blog_page_content_before_post_list() {
if ( is_home() ) {
$post = get_page_by_path( ‘/blog’ );
echo wpautop($post->post_content);
}
}
```

Source link – https://presscustomizr.com/snippet/enter-text-posts-static-blog-page/

Method 2:

Assuming you’ve set a custom page for the posts in the WordPress backend (Settings > Reading), you just need to add a few lines of code to your index.php file in your theme. Like so:

//grab the id of the page set in the backend
$posts_page_id = get_option(‘page_for_posts’);

```
//grab the post object related to that id
$posts_page = get_post($posts_page_id);

//display the content if any
if( $posts_page->post_content ){
echo wpautop( $posts_page->post_content ); //uses wpautop to automatically add paragraphs
}
```

Source Link – [Adding static content to Wordpress posts page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589288/adding-static-content-to-wordpress-posts-page)

Method 3:

```
global $post;
$page_for_posts_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
if ( $page_for_posts_id ) : 
    $post = get_page($page_for_posts_id);
    setup_postdata($post);
    ?>
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <header>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->
        <div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', '', $page_for_posts_id); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    rewind_posts();
endif;
```

Source link: https://www.thatweblook.co.uk/tutorial-wordpress-show-content-of-static-posts-page-above-posts-list/?unapproved=11768&moderation-hash=f5c2e41fcea7e044a9e46798f94703dd#comment-11768